# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException in WCF Java Client

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am developing Java client for C# web service/WCF. While accessing the function through my java client I am getting  `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException`. I am java guy, I don't know anything about C#.
I am not able to find problem. Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
Service1 service1=new Service1();
IService1 iService1=service1.getBasicHttpBindingIService1();
System.out.println("-->>  "+iService1.getData(10));  // this function works fine
System.out.println("-->>  "+iService1.devicePNP(100)); // error line
```

Error description/stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.devicePNP(Unknown Source)
at demo.Check.main(Check.java:34)
```

Comment: **The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. ** You need to check the server hosting the service (or talk to whoever owns it), as the error is on their side.

Comment: Yeah agreed speak to the server side guys and see what is causing the problem. Get a copy of SOAP UI and run the request that creates the error. You can then send them the actual request as well which will help with debugging information.

Comment: Thnk you , Yes it was server side error.